# adding pgfkeys to tikz \fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pgfkeys

Trying to make a new command expanding tikz I got stuck changing the color for the used `\fill` macro.
Any construction of `.unknown-handler` or `.search also={/tikz}` failed.
The solution in [Pass key option inside a macro to a TikZ drawing command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109596/pass-key-option-inside-a-macro-to-a-tikz-drawing-command) adds the keys to `\begin{tikzpicture}` instead of `\fill`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\tikwidth

\pgfkeys{/tikzTest/.cd,
         TestWidth/.code = \setlength{\tikwidth}{#1},
         /tikzTest/.search also = {/tikz},
        }

%%%% userlevel call \Block[]()()
\def\Block[#1]#2#3{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzTest/.cd,#1}
    \fill (#2) rectangle (#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}
  \Block[color=red] {0,0}{0.5,0.5}
  \Block[color=blue] {0.5,0.5}{1,1};
\end{document}
```

which gives me two black squares instead of one red and one blue.

I'm out of ideas of what I'm missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgfkeys` does not set the options for the current picture or path.  Therefore you have to pass the options to the picture directly.

You should also use `\newcommand` for optional argument, so it doesn't fail if the optional argument is not there and you will want to remove the line endings using `%` to prevent spurious spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\tikwidth

\pgfkeys{
  /tikzTest/.cd,
  TestWidth/.code = \setlength{\tikwidth}{#1},
  /tikzTest/.search also = {/tikz},
}

%%%% userlevel call \Block[]()()
\newcommand\Block[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[/tikzTest/.cd,#1]
    \fill (#2) rectangle (#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\Block[fill=red]{0,0}{0.5,0.5}
\Block[fill=blue]{0.5,0.5}{1,1}
\Block{0,0}{.5,.5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for the MWE it works - but not for the original code. It's a part of 50Mb of a book - guess I have the error somewhere else, so I have to look over again. Thx anyway - and for the `newcommand` - I just hardcoded it for the MWE. I'm 30yrs in tex now and the original is using oldstyle `\@ifnextchar [`... By the way - you also added `\begin{tikzpicture}[/tikzTest/.cd,#1]`.  I'll give it a try with `\fill[/tikzTest/.cd,#1]`...

Comment: that does it - at least partly. Since the boxes are part of a bigger picture I replaced `\begin{tikzpicture}[/tikzTest/.cd,#1]` by a `\begin{scope}[/tikzTest/.cd,#1]` and voilà. What confused me is that in the original scope shift does not work in a situation where you place the boxes via anchors related to tcolorboxes...

Answer (score 0):

You can force the options to take place by `every path` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\tikwidth
\pgfkeys{
  /tikzTest/.is family,
  /handler config=full or existing,
  /tikzTest/.search also={/tikz},
  /tikzTest/TestWidth/.code = \setlength{\tikwidth}{#1}
}

%%%% userlevel call \Block[]()()
\def\Block[#1]#2#3{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzTest/.cd,every path/.append style={#1}}
    \path (#2) rectangle (#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
  \Block[fill=red,line width=1.4mm,draw=yellow] {0,0}{0.5,0.5}
  \Block[fill=blue] {0.5,0.5}{1,1};
\end{document}
```

[image]